# How to use justify content property in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, styling

I'm trying to align contents to the left of image.But here what I'm getting is the text will take the left out space after the image.I'm expecting the `float-align:left` property just as in css to be here.So that I've used `alignItems:flex-end`.But not getting the output.Is there any possibility of doing this.What I've tried is as below

**updated**

```
<ScrollView>
    {article.map(a =>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate('Article')}>
      <CardSection>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
       <Image source={{uri:a.poster}} style={styles.thumbnail_style}/>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 
      {a.title}</Text>
    </View>
      </CardSection>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({   
    thumbnail_style :{
        height: 50,
        width:50,
                },
    textStyle:{
        paddingTop:20,
    fontSize:16,
    paddingLeft:10,
    marginRight:20
    }
});
```

What I'm getting is as below

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Instead of using one element use two elements then try using flex.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: I have not used react but I can provide the normal example will it work? What is your exact requirement how do want it to show can you give me that screen shot too

Comment: No I've tried that based on the concept of `css` style property .Anyway thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you explain why you are setting the `Image` inside your `Text`?
If you want the image on top of the text simply do:

```js
<Image />
<Text></Text>
```

otherwise, if you want them placed from left to right you can wrap them in a view and use `flexDirection`

```js
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Text></Text>
  <Image />
</View>
```

```
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
 <Image
 style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
 source = {{ uri: `https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg` }}/>
 <Text style = {{padding:10, flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>my text</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: flexDirection: 'row' is the correct way to approach this.

Comment: Cool its working , but as I need some spacing between image and text i used `paddingLeft` but the text get clipped off.How do I avoid that?

Comment: Are you using expo? if you are you can toggle the element inspector to see how your changes are altering the view. In any case are you aware of the differences between `margin` and `padding`? Use `marginLeft` instead. You might also want to research a little bit about `flex`

Comment: No I'm not using expo.Btw I've tried `marginLeft` as well.Yeah for sure.

Comment: @anu okay in your styles.textStyle, change it to `flex:1` and `flexWrap: 'wrap'`

Comment: Hey but that will remove my text.Now I can see only images.

Comment: I see...however, it works for me. Kindly refer to the last section in my updated answer to see if it it's the same. Maybe you or I missed something

Comment: Hm..that doesn't seems to be working.By removing `flex:1`.I'm getting something like this for the above code you've shared. 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/299nT.png

Comment: Oops I forgot to add `flexDirection: 'row'`, but it should work. I apologize if I am unable to help you

Comment: Sorry to say, none of the above works for me.Text is getting clipped even if I increased `fontSize`.Anyway thank you so much for the help.Let me try.

Comment: I solved this issue.It was my mistake I was using smaller values for `marginRight`.But once I changed it to greater values , I got the output

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are wrapping `Image` inside `Text`. Since you want `Image` and `Text` to appear side by side you need it to be siblings. You can have like:

```
<View>
 <Image />
 <Text />
</View>
```

Then you can apply following style to `View`

```
{
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: 'flex-start'
}
```